# Two RSS feeds, different items limit?

Tags: rss, feed

I have two RSS feed on my Wordpress blog:

1. mydomain.com/feed/
2. mydomain.com/feed/anotherfeed/

Is it possible to set different items limits on these? I want to show 10 items for the first feed, but the second I want to show 30 items.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can. First create the feed [as per codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_feed):

```
function anotherfeed_init(){
    add_feed('anotherfeed');
}
add_action('init', 'anotherfeed_init');
```

Now, [change the post count](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) for this particular feed:

```
function anotherfeed_post_count( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_main_query() && is_feed('anotherfeed') )
        $query->set( 'posts_per_rss', 30 );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'anotherfeed_post_count' );
```

Comment: Where do you suggest I should place the anotherfeed_post_count function? (In which file)

Comment: Both go in `functions.php`

Comment: Note that the first function will need a callback to achieve the kind of feed you want to display there. That's why I included the link to the codex.

Comment: Maybe better add that to a custom plugin. Feeds should not be feed-dependent.

Comment: @kaiser You mean theme dependent? That's true.

Comment: @cjbj hehe … yes, I meant _theme_ dependent :)